# Две @OneToOne Hibernate аннотации в одном Entity

Tags: java, hibernate

Я пытаюсь написать запрос который будет выдавать все Entity из бд которые проходят фильтрацию, однако у меня возникает конфликт так-как я использую в одном Entity два других Entity используя аннотацию @OneToOne

```
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = Vote.DELETE, query = "DELETE FROM Vote v WHERE v.id=:id AND v.user.id=:userId"),
        @NamedQuery(name = Vote.GET_ALL, query = "SELECT v FROM Vote v WHERE v.user.id=:userId ORDER BY v.date")
})
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_votes", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"user_id", "date"}, name = "users_votes_unique_date_idx"))
public class Vote extends AbstractBaseEntity {
    public static final String DELETE = "Vote.delete";
    public static final String GET_ALL = "Vote.getAll";

    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "global_seq", foreignKeyDefinition = "START WITH 100"))
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Null
    private User user;

    @JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "global_seq", foreignKeyDefinition = "START WITH 100"))
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Null
    private Restaurant restaurant;

    @Column(name = "date", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now()")
private LocalDateTime date;
```

Так-же в классе есть конструкторы (пустой, для клонирования и тот, который принимает все параметры), сеттеры и геттеры всех полей и toString.

При попытке создать namedQuery с параметрами (Vote.GET_ALL, Vote.class) вылетает ошибка

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.train4game.munoon.model.Restaurant

Думал решить проблему с помощью LEFT JOIN FETCH но он принимает только одно поле, мне нужно два.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решил добавлением двух аннотаций

```
@JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "global_seq", foreignKeyDefinition = "START WITH 100"))
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@Null
private Restaurant restaurant;
```